# Uncountable monochromatic set

Tags: graph-theory, ramsey-theory, infinitary-combinatorics

Maybe you can help me with that. I was asking myself if you take an uncountable set $S$ and let $S^{(2)}$ be 2-coloured, must there exist an uncountable monochromatic set in $S$?

Comment: What exactly is the difficulty you have in answering this?

Comment: What do you mean by $S^2$?

Comment: The set $X^{(r)}$ is the set of all $r$-tuples of a finite set $X$

Comment: My problem is how to approach the problem

Comment: You do not mean $r$-tuples, because then you can avoid monochromatic sets by coloring the diagonal different from the rest. Perhaps you mean sets of size $r$, which is the usual interpretation and how I have answered the question. Also, $S$ is infinite, so saying that $X$ is finite is probably a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not necessarily. A standard counterexample is Sierpiński's coloring: Well-order the reals, and color $\{a,b\}$ blue if the usual ordering and the well-ordering coincide on $\{a,b\}$, and red otherwise. An uncountable monochromatic set would give us a subset of $\mathbb R$ of order type $\omega_1$ (or its reverse) in the usual ordering, and this is impossible. (Note that if $S^{(2)}$ is the collection of $2$-sized tuples, then a counterexample is trivially obtained by coloring the diagonal different from the rest.)

What is true is that if $S$ has size at least $|\mathbb R|^+$, then $2$-colorings of the collection $S^{(2)}$ of *subsets* of $S$ of size $2$ give us uncountable monochromatic sets, this is a particular case of a result of Erdős and Rado. The study of these extensions of Ramsey's theorem in called the [partition calculus](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1956-62-05/S0002-9904-1956-10036-0/S0002-9904-1956-10036-0.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for you answer, just be sure. What do you mean with order type $\omega_1$? With $\{a,b\}$ you refer to colouring the vertices a,b and not the edge which connects the two vertices, correct?

Comment: Yes, I am only coloring the vertices. By $\omega_1$ I mean the [first uncountable ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal). If you are not familiar with ordinals, what I wrote is probably not clear. But this is essentially unavoidable, since we cannot give a purely explicit arguments; for instance, Galvin proved that if $S=\mathbb R$ and the coloring has the Baire property, then there is an uncountable monochromatic set. But we cannot produce colorings lacking the Baire property without a nontrivial appeal to the axiom of choice.

Comment: (By "Yes, I am only coloring the vertices", I obviously mean "No, I am coloring the edges." Apologies for the typo.)